# Changing hidden Paypal value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I've got 2 dropdowns

This is part of a form to buy either a Short Sleeve or Long Sleeve shirt using Paypal.

Short Sleeve is one price. Long Sleeve is another price. That works great. Using hidden values I can make a 2XL and 3XL Short Sleeve shirt change price. That works great.

The javascript is used to change the pricing for 2XL and 3XL Long Sleeve shirts. 
This also works great. The problem I'm having is making the option_select values change to say "LS 2XL" or "LS 3xL" instead of "SS 2XL" or "SS 3XL" (along with the rest of the Long sleeve sizes).

I'm not proficient in javascript, but I can usually piece enough together to make thing work. This one has me stumped. Any help using javascript would be appreciated.

```js
function changeHiddenInput(objDropDown) {
  var upcharge2XL = document.getElementById("hiddenvalue2XL");
  var upcharge3XL = document.getElementById("hiddenvalue3XL");
  upcharge2XL.value = 20.00;
  upcharge3XL.value = 21.00;
}
```

```html
<select name="amount" size="1" id="Combobox1"  onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
  <option value="15.00">Short Sleeve</option>
  <option value="18.00">Long Sleeve</option>
</select><br/>
<select name="os0" size="1" id="Combobox2">
  <option selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="SS Small">Small</option>
  <option value="SS Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="SS Large">Large</option>
  <option value="SS XL">XL</option>
  <option value="SS 2XL">2XL + $2</option>
  <option value="SS 3XL">3XL + $3</option>
  <option value="--------">--------</option>
  <option value="SS Youth Small">Youth Small</option>
  <option value="SS Youth Medium">Youth Medium</option>
  <option value="SS Youth Large">Youth Large</option>
</select><br/>
Hidden Paypal Values

<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="SS 2XL" id="hiddensize2XL">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="17.00" id="hiddenvalue2XL">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="SS 3XL" id="hiddensize3XL">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="18.00" id="hiddenvalue3XL">
```

Comment: Would it be a solution to make 2 different selects, one for [short sleeve]/[long sleeve] and then another for the different sizes? Then you can piece together the combination and calculate the price as you wish.

Comment: Yes, I considered 2 selects (one for each sleeve type), but wanted to make it easy on the customer. Currently, I'm using a LONG dropdown that includes both short sleeve sizes and long sleeve sizes, but the customer has to make sure when they select (for example: long sleeve) in the first drop down, that they also select the long sleeve size and not a short sleeve size or the order will display wrong in the Paypal cart.

Comment: I see - I meant one where they choose either short/long sleeve, then another one where they choose size (assuming both are available in all sizes). Then you have the information of both and can calculate and and display a value accordingly!

Comment: Here is a link to the page where this is used. Maybe it will be clearer.[link](http://harvilledesign.com/harvilledesign/shop_WALarkspur.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this?

```js
document.getElementById("pp1").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove this line when finished testing
  const sleeve = document.getElementById("Combobox1").value;
  const size = document.getElementById("Combobox2").value;
  if (sleeve === "" || size === "") {
    alert("Please choose sleeves and size")
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  }
  let amt = sleeve === "SS" ? 15 : 17;
  if (size === "2XL") amt += 2;
  else if (size === "3XL") amt += 3;
  document.getElementById("hiddensize2XL").value=size
  document.getElementById("hiddensize3XL").value=size
  document.getElementById("hiddenvalue2XL").value = amt.toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById("hiddenvalue3XL").value = amt.toFixed(2);
})
```

```html
<select name="amount" size="1" id="Combobox1">
  <option value="" selected>Sleeves</option>
  <option value="SS">Short Sleeve</option>
  <option value="LS">Long Sleeve</option>
</select><br/>
<select name="os0" size="1" id="Combobox2">
  <option value="" selected>Select Size</option>
  <option value="Small">Small</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="Large">Large</option>
  <option value="XL">XL</option>
  <option value="2XL">2XL + $2</option>
  <option value="3XL">3XL + $3</option>
  <option value="--------">--------</option>
  <option value="Youth Small">Youth Small</option>
  <option value="Youth Medium">Youth Medium</option>
  <option value="Youth Large">Youth Large</option>
</select><br/>
Hidden Paypal Values

<form id="pp1">
<input type="text" name="option_select0" value="" id="hiddensize2XL">
<input type="text" name="option_amount0" value="17.00" id="hiddenvalue2XL">
<input type="teyxt" name="option_select1" value="" id="hiddensize3XL">
<input type="teyt" name="option_amount1" value="18.00" id="hiddenvalue3XL">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm currently not able to get it to work for my problem, but it could be that I'm doing something wrong. I'll keep playing around with your answer and maybe I can get it to work.

Comment: The javascript I'm using changes the price like I need it too, but the problem I'm having is I also need to change the wording that shows up in the Paypal cart. Right now, no matter if I choose a Short Sleeve shirt or a Long Sleeve shirt it still shows SS (short sleeve). Please see the [link](http://harvilledesign.com/harvilledesign/shop_WALarkspur2.html) and add a long sleeve 2XL to your cart and see that the price changes, but the sleeve length description still says SS 2XL.

Comment: Can you make a test page and add my script?

Comment: Please click the link again. I added your script, but kept my form. I know this doesn't work, but maybe it will help make things easier to see what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Make the hidden field visible in a test form on another page and try to debug. I was only guessing based on what you posted but do not have time to customise the solution

Comment: I appreciate the help and your code works in your example, but I don't think this works in an actual Paypal form. I just need for the osO value that shows up in the Paypal cart to change if a long sleeve shirt is selected. I'm beginning to think this is just not possible.

Comment: Ok, I think part of the problem of why it doesn't work for me is that in my form, the hidden ID "amount" is a Paypal attribute. In my previous form, I had the values of the short sleeve as 15.00 and the long sleeve as 18.00. In your example form, you have the short sleeve value as SS and long sleeve value as LS. This causes an error after submitting the form to Paypal as the value has to be a monetary number.

Comment: Ah, sorry. This is something I could not guess